# Do we need code formatting?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, markdown, formatting

It seems to be that quite a few questions and answers include code. Examples are:

- [What's the symbol that makes one action unique?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/332/whats-the-symbol-that-makes-one-action-unique)
- [Can someone explain the transaction struct?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/102/can-someone-explain-the-transaction-struct)
- [Is there any incentives to run a full node without being one of the 21 block producer?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/125/is-there-any-incentives-to-run-a-full-node-without-being-one-of-the-21-block-pro)
- [nodeos won't run properly, gives time error (Ubuntu 16.04 VM)](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/331/nodeos-wont-run-properly-gives-time-error-ubuntu-16-04-vm)
- https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/55/508
- https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/309/508
- [Why are string-related data types like account_name from type uint64_t?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/q/307/508)

So, do we need code highlighting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now enabled across the site, but you likely won't see it being applied because of your tagging structure. Normally, syntax highlighting is set on each tag, but since questions here don't really use language tags, there's nothing to attach those defaults to for highlighting and it will mostly be manual.

We can, however, set a single language to highlight by default across the entire site if all code is mostly done in the same language. Taking a cursory glance around at example, it's looking like that's mostly be lang-c - so we could set that as the global default and any cases where that's *not* appropriate could override it manually. Just let us know.

Comment: Hi, thanks @animuson and welcome to this site ;)

Comment: Thanks! A global lang-cpp tag would be nice!

Comment: @TeeAttack42 We set global highlighting to "default" since that works very well for C++, but will not completely break if someone decides to post something else, like XML.

Answer (score 3):

I think @mee is correct, to enable **colors** highlighting it appears we need to:

- request through a feature request that certain languages be enabled (say `lang-cpp`) which would allow users to provide language hints in their answers such as `<!-- language: lang-cpp -->`. Language hints on eosio.stackexchange are currently ignore, and syntax highlighting just defaults to `grey`.
- and also we could request that some **tags** be associated with a default language. The default language for all tags `lang-none` which again is just plain `grey`.

For more info see the  **Note  to editors** in this answer: [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)

Comment: Any progress on this? Syntax highlighting would be really useful

Comment: I am not sure how to move this forward, I think one of our mods might need to get involved, I've tried pinging them.

Comment: I will investigate how to raise this feature-request correctly!

Comment: I have written a message to @RobertCartaino (our stackexchange community manger). Will keep you guys updated.

Answer (score 0):

We already have code highlighting. It's great to have since people are often cross referencing EOS code or github snippets.

You can either do multiline:

```
multiline
code
```

Or section of a paragraph `like this`.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/185661

Comment: Yes but it does not seem to be enabled

Comment: I mean: Yes there is code formatting, but no code highlighting (colors) enabled